# Javascript restrict the images in a row

Tags: javascript

I have total 4 images. i want to show the 2 images in a row.

this is my static html file, i need to generate dynamically using javascript

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div>imag1</div>
  <div>imag2</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div>imag3</div>
  <div>imag4</div>
</div>
```

### javascript

```
for(var i = 1; i <= images.length; i++){

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="row-img">imag1</div>
  <div class="row-img">imag2</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="row-img">imag3</div>
  <div class="row-img">imag4</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var rowImg=document.getElementsByClassName('row-img');

for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
  rowImg[i].appendChild(images[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use JS? You can do this via css..

```
div.row-img{
    width : 48%;
    display : inline-block;
}
```